# Building custom R package leads to undefined symbol

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

I'm currently working on a R package that depends on Eigen, EigenRand, and GSL. I was able to successfully build the package when it just depended on Eigen and GSL. Now, when I build, the compile is successful, but R is not able to link the .so file.

this is my Makevars file:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` `gsl-config --libs`
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I '/path/to/include/eigen-3.4.0' -I '/path/to/include/EigenRand'
```

this is the error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pkgname’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpwgpGqO/Rinst855c41160545/00LOCK-pkgname/00new/pkgname/libs/pkgname.so':
  /tmp/RtmpwgpGqO/Rinst855c41160545/00LOCK-pkgname/00new/pkgname/libs/pkgname.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Rcpp9RcppEigen10eigen_wrapIN5Eigen5ArrayIiLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEEEEP7SEXPRECRKT_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I’ve changed the actual name to “pkgname” where it fits.

I was able to successfully compile and link to a package when the code just involved Eigen and GSL so I don’t think it’s a problem with these two libraries, and installing RcppEigen led to error with unknown includes, so I didn’t switch to RcppEigen.

Edit: I think I can reproduce the problem with this setup. I guess I couldn't build with Eigen, but because I didn't return the array created with Eigen, the compiler optimised it away for me. I would still be interested in knowing what went wrong though because even if I were to use the RcppEigen library, I still need to import EigenRand, which does not have a R package yet.

src/pkgexports.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

List pkgfn();
RcppExport SEXP pkgfn_pkgfn() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject __result;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type seed(seedSEXP);

    __result = Rcpp::wrap(pkgfn());
    return __result;
END_RCPP
}
```

src/pkgfn.cpp:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Rcpp::List;
using Rcpp::_;
using namespace Eigen;

List pkgfn(){
    ArrayXd r_beta = ArrayXd::Random(4);
    return List::create(_["r_beta"] = r_beta);
}
```

Makevars:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I '/usr/local/include/eigen3'
```

Edit2: I've installed all other libraries using Mamba/Conda in another enviroment, but because Eigen & EigenRand doesn't seem to have channels for that I have installed them from source and added them to `/usr/local/include`

Comment: There isn't enough here for us to say anything meaningful.  Obviously, _lots_ of packages build against RcppGSL and RcppEigen.  The former requires linking, the latter doesn't _because the parts of Eigen it uses are header-only_.  We do not have your package so there is not much we can say but if you need the actual Eigen library to link to have 'EigenRand' working you need a different setup.  (And just as an aside `Rcpp::LdFlags()` has not been needed for about a decade.  As mentioned you do need the RcppGSL one for the GSL library.

Comment: Thank you! So what setup are you referencing what would enable me to link to the actual library? 

P.S. I guess I’m not building with RcppEigen, because I am including the eigen library directly in the cpp-flags?

Comment: In short: "this can all be way more complicated" than the char limit of these comment boxen.  Here is the most recent answer I gave on this, it has pointers to a short pa[er / write up that is also a vignette in the package: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73347200/revisions  If you need an external library, things are hardest.  If you use new header files you have make sure potential users have those. If it just for your local use case that matters less.

Comment: But starting from the top and with the simplest answer: An error "undefined symbol" means your code references something but doesn't supply it.  Omitting library is a common cause.

Comment: So from what I understand, the simplest way to get things working is to add the libraries to src? I’ll try that today and report back. Thank you!

Comment: P.s. I’m also curious why the code could have referenced something that doesn’t exist but then it compiles successfully? (With R CMD build)

Comment: If you spend more time at StackOverflow, you will notice that question askers are frequently encouraged to provide [minimally complete verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and for example a pointer to a repo can help. As for your PS: that is one of the difference between _compiling_ (which passed, making valid references to external code) and _linking_ which has to ensure the code is there, eg in a library.  Lastly editing your question to properly format code is also appreciated.

Comment: I removed the RcppEigen. You don't use that it seems.

Comment: Hi! Much of the resources on the internet refers to libraries that have compiled binaries/libraries. Both Eigen and EigenRand claim to be entirely written with headers and does not need to be built. I still followed the instructions and installed Eigen into my /usr/local/include, but it does not seem to change anything. So I am a bit confused as to what's going on here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I pointed you to my vignette and paper, it is pretty explicit about header libraries.

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured out the problem. It has nothing to do with missing some binary or something like that. Instead, it's simply a problem with Rcpp not being able to accept ArrayXd as an element. However, instead of outputting a compile time error, Rcpp outputs an error when using the library saying that the element does not exist, leading me to this tangent where I thought there was something wrong with including Eigen.

Comment: Glad you made progress.  Simple fact is that you do not type converters "for free" or "just by wishing for them".  RcppEigen does what it does, for the known and declared types it does it for.  Everything else that may be missing "someone" will have to add. Just because something has 'eigen' in its name does not mean somebody already wrote a converter.  Lastly, and in case that was not obvious, you do not get RcppEigen type converters unless you include RcppEigen headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem. There was nothing wrong with including the libraries.

src/pkgfn.cpp:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Rcpp::List;
using Rcpp::_;
using namespace Eigen;

List pkgfn(){
    ArrayXd r_beta = ArrayXd::Random(4);
    auto r_beta_vec = vector<double>(r_beta.data(), r_beta.data()+4);
    return List::create(_["r_beta"] = r_beta_vec);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write that this way (and note that the `[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]` would not be needed in your test package, just have a `LinkingTo: RcppEigen` there).

In particular the second one-line version is pretty good, but if you want to get by with just `Rcpp` you can also use the first.

##### Code

```
#include <RcppEigen.h> // single header all you need

// need just for the Rcpp::sourceCpp() demo
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> pkgfun() {
    Eigen::ArrayXd r_beta = Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(4);
    auto r_beta_vec = std::vector<double>(r_beta.data(), r_beta.data()+4);
    return r_beta_vec;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::ArrayXd pkgfun2() {
    return Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(4);
}

/*** R
pkgfun()
pkgfun2()
*/
```

##### Output

Calling `sourceCpp()` compiles, links and loads the code -- and also sources the R portion at the bottom inside `/*** R ... */` for you:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/76600261/answer.cpp")

> pkgfun();
[1] -0.9803230 -0.2274045  0.0327535  0.8861597

> pkgfun2()
[1] -0.427496 -0.891072  0.897365 -0.876335
>
```